# How do I get the HTML hex color corresponding to a color on screen?

Tags: color, color-profile, color-spaces

I need to render rectangles in HTML/CSS that exactly match rectangles in PowerPoint.  How do I get the hex color code?

Presumably the Mac Digital Color Meter Tool is the tool for the job.  But me and a colleague get two different values for the same color, and even stranger, I get different values from the same machine after pasting a screen capture of it.

How could two MacBook Pro machines looking at the same document get different readings from the Digital Color Meter tool, different enough that the client notices when rendered in HTML:

One machines says `"#009CDD"` and the other says `"#3189D7"`, as in the two images below.

- Both are measuring sRGB, so it's not a different color space
- Both have large apertures, so its' not due to aliasing
- Both machines have Night Shift not enabled
- Both machines have color profile "Color LCD"
- Both machines have same Profile settings u

[image]
[image]

(Edit, second image first attached was taken while debugging, deleted now, seeking the original image)

And now here, after pasting the first image and pointing the DCM at that, it returns a different read:

[image]

Comment: Are they both reading the document in the same application? And is it actually copies of _the same file_, not two different versions of the document? Could you add an image for the other machine as well?

Comment: Calibrated both machines? Just because the manufacturer maybe the same.. not all LCD screens are identical to their same make/model counterparts. Each screen needs to be independently calibrated.. and if trying to match.. they need to be calibrated under an *identical* ambient setting.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, both using Microsoft PowerPoint opening the same doc from GoogleDrive.  Second image added.

Comment: @Scott   I know calibration affects what the human outside the machine sees on screen, but does it affect what the Digital Color Meter inside the machine thinks it sees?    What is really strange is now that I paste the pictures, the Digital Color Meter returns different answer for even these images.

Comment: I rephrased the main question to focus on the actual goal: getting the hex color code to use in HTML to match a shape in PowerPoint.

Comment: Those are clearly different applications (or versions, presumably), though – ‘Color LCD’ is plain text in one but in a white box in the other. Even so, if it really is the same file, the colours should be the same regardless of the app (unless there’s something going on with colour profiles supported by one but not the other). The third value you’re getting on the embedded image is in Generic RGB, not sRGB, so probably because uploading here removed the colour profile.

Comment: Calibration isn't just for the "human eye". It alters how the diodes output color. This is why, for accurate calibration, you need an external calibrating device... and why printers are calibrated, and why scanners are calibrated. Unless **everything** has been calibrated, variances will always be present. My eyes **clearly** tell me those are two different appearing blues... thus... calibration does not match and the DCM is reflecting that mismatch.

Comment: --This is somewhat tricky because things have been uploaded/downloaded etc... but [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iTTj.png) you can see the variance between the two images. I merely cropped, masked and resaved for web (sRGB no profile). My point is.. if two machine show the expected same color differently, then there's something different within the machines - if they have not been calibrated, that is the most likely culprit. DCM is merely reflecting what the respective screen is displaying based upon it's *current calibration*.

Comment: In addition.... Microsoft applications are *notorious* for **not** retaining colors properly. Especially in the blue range. The entire issue *could* very well be Powerpoint itself.

Comment: @Scott well its probably related to the fact that microsofts icm is set to saturation intent for power point. The purpose of saturation mode is to find as vibrant match as possible within a range.

Comment: @joojaa PowerPoint doesn't do color management; it relies on whatever the system provides. MacOS's color management is a bit bizarre in some respects, at least in some versions. For example, if you create a rectangle in PPT, assign it whatever color you like, then add some text atop it and assign the text the same color, you'll still be able to see the text. It should be invisible ... same color as the shape behind it, after all ... but since the OS seems to manage text/shapes differently, they come out in different colors.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Ah but thats a conflation issue.

Comment: For the record, there are better third party applications for picking colors from any application. The best free (freemium) one currently is [ColorSlurp](https://colorslurp.com/). The other two contenders are [Sip](https://sipapp.io/) and [ColorSnapper](https://colorsnapper.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is not an issue of calibration but colors actually rendering differently in different applications and on different machines, even slightly different years of MacBook Pro with the same detailed settings.

Rendered within a browser with HTML/CSS , the Digital Color Meter reads the exact same color as specified on three different machines.

However, entering a color #009CDD as a custom color in PowerPoint, it can render as #009CDE, #339CDF

Viewing the PowerPoint over screenshare like Zoom changes the color even further, to #469ADA.

Multiple transformations, such opening a PowerPoint, sharing it over Zoom, taking a screenshot of that screenshare, and attaching it as an email can change the color further yet, even to #5597D0 and #569CD9.

Comment: Why is it suprising to you that low quality yuv compression changes color?

Comment: @joojaa Good point.  My only real surprise in retrospect is that PowerPoint renders a shape with a specific hex color differently even on similar os.

Comment: Yes but that entirely depends on how you define color. Do you define color as same value or as same apparent reaction in brain.